# How do I get the association bonus if someone moved my post to another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: bug, reputation, questions, migration, association-bonus

I originally asked the question [Which heat pad content materials will keep me warm the longest?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/169051/104410) on Physics Stack Exchange - it was my first question on the site - and I think I got the association bonus after registering (at least I have it now). Someone then moved that question to Chemistry Stack Exchange, where I did not have an account before.

Now the question is on Chemistry SE and I have an account there, but I am still at 1 reputation.

How do I get the association bonus of 100 points for Chemistry Stack Exchange?

Comment: try logging our and back in again. Thats the best I can think of.

Comment: The timeline doesn't show when it was migrated, perhaps just waiting a bit (24 hrs?) might allow the system to catch up.

Comment: You got the bonus in Feb 5, 2021 already, you can't get the bonus again. Check your deleted questions or answers to see why you lost 100 reputation without a trace, likely a post of your was marked as spam, which results in a -100 reputation penalty.

Comment: @V2Blast how come the revisions on Chemistry.SE don't show the question was migrated? Can you see what went wrong with your magic tools please? I got why no association bonus (see previous comment) but it does not explain the weirdness of invisible migration. :/

Comment: I have no idea either. The only question I see by Kjara on Physics.SE is this one that they asked yesterday (which was closed for being about engineering rather than about the science itself): [Which plastics let infrared (middle and long) through?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/735747/148225) (Searching Physics.SE for `heat pad content materials` also doesn't show any results.)

Comment: @V2Blast thanks, so I believe the OP got confused with the sites, i.e. posted in on Chemistry to begin with, thinking it's Physics. With almost exact same design and look, it's very easy to get confused between SE sites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, your question was never migrated. When a question is migrated, there is a clear banner saying so that appears for 60 days after migration, e.g., [this question](https://wordpress.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4790/why-are-wordpress-open-source-free-plugins-questions-not-allowed-in-wordpress-se) that was migrated from here to a different site:

[image: Migration banner on a migrated question]

There is no such banner on your question in Chemistry, and neither any indication in the revisions or elsewhere. This means you posted the question originally in Chemistry, thinking by mistake you were on Physics. Having very similar design and look, that's an expected mistake, all good.

As for your association bonus on Chemistry.SE, you got it already when you created your account there:

[image: User got their association bonus]

That is because you had over 200 reputation on a different site at that time already, so any new account is given the +100 bonus upon creation.

The association bonus is not given again when you post your first question; it's given only once.

The reason you have only 1 reputation is something that was deleted, either a [deleted question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-questions/current), or a [deleted answer](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/users/deleted-answers/current).

Comment: For clarity, the migration notice is hidden once 60 days have passed since the migration.

Comment: @Sonic yeah, but the case here is about a few days old question.

Comment: Well, for someone else reading this answer and seeing your statements that a question without the notice must have not been migrated, it's a source of confusion.

Comment: @Sonic OK that's fair, edited to clarify this.